# Strange Routing Issue Angular 7 + Ionic 4 Beta

Tags: angular, ionic4

I have an Ionic 4 beta app + Angular 7.

It has just been updated from Ionic 4 beta 3 to beta 21 + Angular 6 to Angular 7.1.3.

Since the update none of my routing is working, the url in the address bar changes but the page does not update.

I can see that NavController has been deprecated so I have updated my code to use the built in angular router instead of the NavController but I still have the same issue.

I have added tracing to my routing config

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { enableTracing: true })],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
}
```

And the tracing shows that the routing is all working as expected, and after some debugging I can even see that the constructor of the components I am navigating to, are also executing.

So I looked at the DOM and things are now really strange!

[image]

The component highlighted in blue is the component I navigated to. It is all rendered correctly just not visible. If I edit the DOM and delete the `<app-cases>` "the previous component", then my `<app-case>` component shows correctly.

So it seems the hiding and showing of the next component is not working correctly.

Anyone have any ideas ?

Comment: Does setting the main attribute to the ion-router-outlet help? E.g. `<ion-router-outlet id="content" main></ion-router-outlet>`. Check also that you don't have multiple ion-router-outlets.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @Apeksha No sorry never got to the bottom of this. I even tried creating a new app and copying files into a new solution. The project I was on was just a POC and never came off the Beta version of ionic :/

Comment: @Apeksha see if the fix below sorts this for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So looks like this was down to the following line

```
import "~@ionic/angular/css/core.css";
```

missing in the global.scss

[Render not working after Navigate Ionic 4](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-4-rendering-after-navigate-not-working/150153/2)